# ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort dictionaries in MongoDB. However, I get the value error "too many values to unpack" because I think it's implying that there are too many values in each dictionary (there are 16 values in each one). This is my code:

```
FortyMinute.find().sort(['Rank', 1])
```

Anyone know how to get around this?

EDIT: Full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "main.py", line 21, in main
    fm.readFortyMinute(args[0])
  File "/Users/Yih-Jen/Documents/Rowing Project/FortyMinute.py", line 71, in readFortyMinute
    writeFortyMinute(FortyMinData)
  File "/Users/Yih-Jen/Documents/Rowing Project/FortyMinute.py", line 104, in writeFortyMinute
    FortyMinute.find().sort(['Rank', 1])        
  File "/Users/Yih-Jen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 692, in sort
    self.__ordering = helpers._index_document(keys)
  File "/Users/Yih-Jen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 65, in       _index_document
    for (key, value) in index_list:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Full traceback, please?

Comment: Just edited my question, look there!

Comment: What does a simple `FortyMinute.find()` return?

Comment: @Yeej, are you using some sort of library like **PyMongo**?

Comment: seems like you're passing arguments from like `python main.py arg1 arg2 ...`? Although generally just sort with `.sort('Rank', 1)` should work fine. Perhaps something else is happening while you're passing the arguments? Just a thought

Comment: @Anzel Yes I am using Pymongo!

Comment: I'm guessing you pass your arguments from system like my above comments, and translate into your sort statement. Try this: `FortyMinute.find().sort(Arg1, int(Arg2))` which I think you're passing 1 as sorting direction, however being parsed as **string**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the arguments and values in **unpacked** as so:

```
FortyMinute.find().sort('Rank', 1)
```

---

It is only when you're passing **multiple sort parameters** that you group arguments and values using lists, and then too you must surround all your parameters with a tuple as so:

```
FortyMinute.find().sort([(Rank', 1), ('Date', 1)])
```

---

**Pro-tip:** Even the `Cursor.sort` documentation linked below recommends using `pymongo.DESCENDING` and `pymongo.ASCENDING` instead of 1 and -1; in general, you should use descriptive variable names instead of magic constants in your code as so:

```
FortyMinute.find().sort('Rank',pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

---

Finally, if you are so inclined, you can sort the list using Python's built-in as the another answerer mentioned; but even thought `sorted` accepts iterators and not just sequences it might be more inefficient and nonstandard:

```
sorted(FortyMinute.find(), key=key_function)
```

where you might define `key_function` to return the `Rank` column of a record.

---

[Link to the official documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.sort)

Comment: That returns this error:

    TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list

Comment: @Yeej Could you post the traceback with my updated code?

Comment: @Yeej You can accept my answer by clicking the green check to the left of my post if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want mong/pymongo to sort:

```
FortyMinute.find().sort('Rank', 1)
```

If you want to sort using multiple fields:

```
FortyMinute.find().sort([('Rank': 1,), ('other', -1,)])
```

You also have constants to make it more clear what you're doing:

```
FortyMinute.find().sort('Rank',pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

If you want to sort in python first you have to return the result and use a sorting method in python:

```
sorted(FortyMinute.find(), key=<some key...>)
```

Comment: @Yeej What does a simple `FortyMinute.find()` return?

Comment: FortMinute.find() works just fine because I use it in a for loop to access each dictionary when printing to a text file.

Comment: @Yeej this is identical to the documentation. If this doesn't work something else is broken.